# Disable a pop up page based on a value from another pop up page

Tags: asp.net

On my main page I have two pop up pages.both of them have textboxes to be filled 
By the user with save and close buttons .i need to disable one of the pop up pages if there are values in the other pop up page.how do I accomplish please give in your ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Are the popup Pages independent Web Pages? Do you have access to the Data the TextBox Data From you Webpage? if so, in your page_load, you can check is there exists Data(to be displayed in textbox), and accordingly disable/enable popup links.

Comment: They are independent aspx pages however the controls in them are dynamically added when the popup page link is clicked . So I do not have access to the control ids but the data is being stored in the session how do I disable the link for the other pop up page when the other has data

Comment: Do you use window.open() to popup? or just have a href with a target of new window? session may not work as controls are dynamically built and submitted independently by the respective page, there is no way for the main page to know it unless it postsback

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i got you

you are saying they are two popup pages r u opening two pages in popup than you should not be doing that place the HTML in your page and open in the popup rather than the pages.

Any ways when ever your first popup is open and data has been validated you can make the link for second pop up visible false or disable it and it can be done on both server as well as client side.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to achieve with code for server or client side.

Comment: yup  if the controls are dynamically added  than do some thing on client side.

You add the control dynamically in some div or table

    function validate Data()
    {
    var textValue = $("#dvParent").Find('input type:text');
    
    //dvparent is the id of your control you r adding controls.
    if(textVlaue.val() !=null)
    {
    
    //disable the link
    }
}

this is rough draft i ope you got the point call this function on button client side event of the popup.

Comment: Thankyou for your input will try it out